# How to add unique UUID in every Request in Spring Based Java application

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I have just started working on spring boot application.
I want to append unique UUID to every API request and append it to the log.

I have written 
    public class RequestContextListener  implements ServletRequestListener {

```
private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

@Override
public void requestInitialized(ServletRequestEvent arg0) {
    logger.debug("++++++++++++ REQUEST INITIALIZED +++++++++++++++++");
    MDC.put("UUID", UUID.randomUUID());
}

@Override
public void requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent arg0) {
    logger.debug("-------------REQUEST DESTROYED ------------");
    MDC.clear();
}
```

Below is my logback-spring.xml file changes

```
 <property name="CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN" value="%clr(%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}){faint} %clr(%5p) %clr(${PID:- }){magenta} %clr(---){faint} %clr([%15.15t]){faint} %clr(%-40.40logger{39}){cyan} %clr(:){faint} %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%rEx} [%X{UUID}]"/>
```

But this is not working for me.
Do I have to mention anywhere that this needs to be executed ?
Please help , I have already wasted one day on this.

Comment: I was missing @Component annotation in my class .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use HandlerInterceptorAdapter in my spring boot app for preventing duplicate posts.

```
@Component
public class ViewInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ViewInterceptor.class);

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        logger.info("...prehandle");
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response, Object handler,
            ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        logger.info("...posthandle");
        super.postHandle(request, response, handler, modelAndView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of a Interceptor I would probably create a     ServletRequestListener as that is executed before all filters.